# Google Reporting API with oauth 2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-reporting-api

I want to use Google Reporting API to get the users' activity report (last login, etc). 
My application is using oauth 2.0 to access other Google APIs. But it seems like  Google Reporting API is not supporting oauth 2.0. Any suggestions how should I do it ? Implement oauth 1 or use different Google API (if it exists) to get users' activity report?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at the old documentation for the reporting API.

For the brand new reports API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/authorizing), it is encouraged to use OAuth 2.0.

Notice that the older API is called reporting API, but the new API that was just released at the IO is called reports API.